# Change Component behaviour based on given attribute

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

how do I create a component in Angular which changes the behaviour based on the given attribute?

Example:

```
<my-comp [data]="data"></my-comp>
```

vs

```
<my-comp [data]="data" sortable> </my-comp>
```

`<my-comp>` is just a `Component` witch shows the data as a html list. Is it possible to check in the `MyComponent`  if the attribute `sortable` is set without using `@Input()`?
Do I have to define a `Directive` or can I somehow access the attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you can do by using `@Attribute` decorator

**my.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <h1>Comp hasSortable {{ hasSortable }}</h1>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  hasSortable: boolean;
  constructor(@Attribute('sortable') private sortable: any) {
    this.hasSortable = sortable !== null;
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<my-comp></my-comp>           // Prints "Child hasSortable false"
<my-comp sortable></my-comp>  // Prints "Child hasSortable true"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/nFaoEJ9lM1PiVDkLd3j0?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
private _sortable:boolean = false;
@Input() sortable(val) {
  if(val) {
    this._sortable = true;
  }
}
```